# Do not re-add build because of unexpected finish in TeamCity

Tags: build, automation, teamcity, teamcity-9.0, devops

How can I disable auto-restart tasks in TeamCity after a failed build? I can't find this option anywhere.

I saw only one message in Overview section after auto-triggered build: "Re-added because of unexpected finish"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a parameter which can be specified on a project or build configuration level:
teamcity.buildQueue.restartBuildAttempts

By default it's value is 3, so TeamCity makes 3 attempts to restart build in case of unexpected finish. You can set it to 0 to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
[Pavel Sher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928109/346561) shows how to disable this functionality.

**Original answer:**
Currently (as of TeamCity version 2017.2), it does not seem possible to disable this "feature".

I searched through the TeamCity documentation, support forum, and issue tracker, but I could not find any more information about this behavior.

I did create a new feature request for them to allow us to disable this functionality:
[TW-53064 - Allow disabling of automatic re-queing after unexpected finish](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-53064)